# Archive Daily But Split Large Log files?

Tags: c#, nlog

I am using Nlog and I want to archive daily into another folder but split the log if it gets too big.

I tried something like this

```
{
  archiveEvery: "Day",
  archiveNumbering: "DateAndSequence",
  archiveAboveSize: "1000"
  archiveFileName: "/archives/nlog.{###}.log,
  filename: "nlog.log"
}
```

Say I got 3MB of log data for 204-02-16. I would ideally like to see this

```
nlog-000.log
nlog-001.log
nlog-002.log
```

Not sure if I can do this as I could not get the first one to have a number, so this is also ok

```
nlog.log
nlog-000.log
nlog-001.log
```

Then when 204-02-17 comes around I would like the above files to be archived into a different folder with a date

```
nlog-20240216.log
nlog-20240216-000.log
nlog-20240216-001.log
```

Right now mine is basically archiving after every 1mb, so I can't get the archiveEvery and Size to work they way I want it to.

Comment: NLog does not support batch file-archive, where it moves all files to archive-folder on day-roll. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FileTarget-Archive-Examples